# How can you recover from disk corruption on a backup drive whilst maintaining all hard links?

Tags: bash, shell-script, rsync, data-recovery, file-metadata

So, I have a scenario that is similar to [How to copy directories with preserving hardlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44247/how-to-copy-directories-with-preserving-hardlinks) that I wish to use however I have corruption from the backup hardlink source.

My Scenario:
1. I backup my system to an external drive using Rsync each night.
2. Each night is in its own folder. (Backup.1, Backup.2, ... Backup.40).
3. I use Hardlinks to reduce the amount of disk required by pointing to the previous folder as the Hardlinks Source (as per man rsync).

This has all been working successfully for quite sometime.

NOW I HAVE A CORRUPTION ON THE EXTERNAL DRIVE!

ALL hardlinks to files that are corrupted are now corrupted (dah) can I easily make a new copy of the corrupted files from my still running system (not corrupted) to a new drive and then use the technique mentioned in [How to copy directories with preserving hardlinks?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44247/how-to-copy-directories-with-preserving-hardlinks) to recover the daily folders.

Do you think this will work?
Any other suggestions appreciated.